EXIFTOOL, track creation date, and timezone
I am trying to make sense of the QuickTime/TrackCreateDate value obtained for a file created by camera recording on an iPhone 15, latest OS.  In this case, I was in Japan at the time.  According to the GetInfo function on Mac when looking at this file (from Photos), the movie was created Tuesday, March 5, 2024, 6:42 PM.  (Fairly certain that was (or approx) the local time in Japan when the video was taken.
Yesterday (May 15), I exported that file (and many others) to external files so they can be included in a video I want to make.  I have media from lots of sources (iPhone, 360 camera, drone) so the goal is to name these files in a logical sense that makes it obvious what was teken when (in relation to the others in the set).
Using EXIFTOOL (which I think is my best option here), I get the following values.
> exiftool -ee  -j -g -c '%.6f -api quicktimeutc' '/pathToFile.mov'|grep Date
    "FileModifyDate": "2024:03:05 18:42:57-05:00",
    "FileAccessDate": "2024:05:16 10:03:50-04:00",
    "FileInodeChangeDate": "2024:05:15 20:32:52-04:00",
    "CreateDate": "2024:03:06 08:42:58",
    "ModifyDate": "2024:03:06 08:42:59",
    "TrackCreateDate": "2024:03:06 08:42:58",
    "TrackModifyDate": "2024:03:06 08:42:59",
    "MediaCreateDate": "2024:03:06 08:42:58",
    "MediaModifyDate": "2024:03:06 08:42:59",
    "CreationDate": "2024:03:06 17:42:57+09:00",

> exiftool -ee -api quicktimeutc  -j -g -c '%.6f '/pathToFile.mov'|grep Date
    "FileModifyDate": "2024:03:05 18:42:57-05:00",
    "FileAccessDate": "2024:05:16 10:03:50-04:00",
    "FileInodeChangeDate": "2024:05:15 20:32:52-04:00",
    "CreateDate": "2024:03:06 03:42:58-05:00",
    "ModifyDate": "2024:03:06 03:42:59-05:00",
    "TrackCreateDate": "2024:03:06 03:42:58-05:00",
    "TrackModifyDate": "2024:03:06 03:42:59-05:00",
    "MediaCreateDate": "2024:03:06 03:42:58-05:00",
    "MediaModifyDate": "2024:03:06 03:42:59-05:00",
    "CreationDate": "2024:03:06 17:42:57+09:00",

I have been under the assumption for a while, that the most reliable (between vendors) value here, is the track creation date.  Not sure if that's still so, or ever was, but it's what I would like to work with.  Although "FileModifyDate" looks like the easy answer here (matches what Mac says), I don't believe it to be a reliable value.
But all the other values seem to be off from the time Mac says.  For example, in the first command output (sans -api flag), the TrackCreateDate is 2024:03:06 08:42:58.  Not sure what time zone that represents, but clearly the date does not match what Mac says.  If this is supposed to be a UTC time, we need to add 9 hours to get the Japan time, and we are then 23 hours off. (17:42 3/6 versus 18:42 3/5).
The -api quicktimeutc flag, changes that value to "2024:03:06 03:42:58-05:00" Of course, that is the same answer as without the flag, but shown in -05:00 time zone (WHY????).
Can someone help me understand what EXIFTOOL is trying to tell me here, or if there is a better tool to retrieve such information?  Strangely, the value that I would consider least reliable (file creation) is the only one that seems to be correct here.  Maybe the problem is my jetlagged brain.
Thanks.

I would suggest not using grep to filter exiftool output, as you lose important data, specifically the group locations, with your command.  Instead, try this command: exiftool exiftool -api quicktimeutc -a -s -g -j -time:all /path/to/files/  This will list only the date/time tags and the groups will be included, as well as duplicated tag names

ExifTool only pulls the literal data stored in the file's EXIF fields. For example, DateTime is the "Date/Time of image was last modified. Data format is "YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS"+0x00, total 20 bytes." DateTimeOriginal is a similar 20-byte field. TimeZoneOffset is a signed short.
Perhaps in the process of moving the file, the device exporting it changes the EXIF data. Note that in the MIT reference sited, DateTimeOriginal is supposed to be invariant, the only field with that comment.

0x9003 DateTimeOriginal    ascii string    20  Date/Time of original image taken. This value should not be modified by user program

You can open an image file in a hex editor, such as HxD and see what is stored in each field, and how it is expressed from ExifTool. My inclination would be to go by DateTimeOriginal, since it is advised that it not be changed (though nothing stops an application from violating that stricture).

The data the OP lists is not EXIF data, it is Quicktime data and much of it is formatted quite differently than EXIF data. Most of it is saved as an integer value and based upon UTC. While the DateTimeOriginal tag can exist in a video file, it is uncommon.

Most of the date/time tags in MP4/Mov files is saved as UTC.  When you add the -api QuickTimeUTC option, the UTC time will be converted to the local time of the computer, which may not be the local time where the video was taken.
There is a problem with your first command.  You are using the -c (-coordFormat) option even though you're not extracting any GPS data.  Additionally, your argument to the -c option is '%.6f -api quicktimeutc', i.e. the -api quicktimeutc is part of the coordinate format, and not a separate option which might be your intent.
But from looking at your data, you say that the video was taken in TZ +09:00.  Looking at the file system time stamps, it appears you are in an East Coast time zone, -05:00 EST/-04:00 EDT.  If this is correct, then most of the time stamps are correct, except for the file system ones.
The CreationDate shows "2024:03:06 17:42:57+09:00". This is probably the local time where the video was shot. Unlike most other video time stamps, it is not saved as UTC and is supposed to be saved as local time.  iPhones will do this and include the local time zone, so this value appears accurate.
The ModifyDate, CreateDate, Track*Date, and Media*Date tags are all supposed to be set to UTC.  Because of the error in your first command, all the output from that command shows the raw, UTC values. When you subtract the +09:00 time zone from the CreationDate, the result is the 2024:03:06 08:42:5* UTC time listed. The seconds are a bit off usually because of the time need to buffer and write the file.
Now going from UTC to the time zone of your computer, -05:00 at the time of the video, you get the 2024:03:06 03:42:5*-05:00 local time.
To summarize, all of these are the same
EST  : 2024:03:06 03:42:5*-05:00
UTC  : 2024:03:06 08:42:5*+00:00
Japan: 2024:03:06 17:42:5*+09:00
The FileModifyDate, which is the file system time stamp, seems to be way off, as it should adjust the same way.  That is, as long as the file systems used were the MacOS or Windows NTFS file systems. That is because these file systems work the same way as the video ones, the time is saved as UTC and adjusted to the local computer's time zone.  If the file ended up on a different file system, such as a FAT32 at some point, that will mess up the file system time stamps, as FAT32 is not saved the same way. Or if it was transferred by uploading to a website or through email/text.
I would not consider the Track*Date/Media*Date tags to be the most reliable because this data is likely to be lost if the video is edited. There aren't a lot of editing programs that will properly save these values. But it seems that in this case the file was not edited.
When the file is from an Apple device, then the CreationDate is most likely to be correct, as long as the device is aware of the current time zone, as would be the case in phones. Accurate date/time tags on devices from other companies are likely to vary by device and comapany.
